# remove cursor if <a> tag carries #

Tags: css

For a project, I've got a dynamic megamenu.

In primary menu I have `<a>` tag which have URL `& #`. I need to assign `cursor:pointer` as `cursor:default` for the `<a>` tag which carries `href="#"`.

Is there any possibilities to control using css

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Dummy</a></li>
  <li><a href="url.htm">Dummy</a></li>
  <li><a href="url.htm">Dummy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to assign `cursor: pointer` or `cursor: default`? They are different.

Comment: Cursor default for #. Pointer for url. I got the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using attribute selectors on the a tag, you can easily detect which links contain a # in their href.

From there, you simply apply the `cursor: default` style to get your desired result.

```css
a[href="#"] { cursor: default }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Dummy</a></li>
  <li><a href="url.htm">Dummy</a></li>
  <li><a href="url.htm">Dummy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: change `cursor:none` to `cursor:default`